# PDFBox: Disable Font Cache or change its location

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I call `PDField.setValue` to set the value for a form field, I get the following stacktrace:

```
FileSystemFontProvider.saveDiskCache(349) | Could not write to font cache
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.pdfbox.cache (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:73)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.saveDiskCache(FileSystemFontProvider.java:290)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:226)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:130)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:149)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:413)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:376)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:350)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:145)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<clinit>(PDType1Font.java:79)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:143)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processSetFont(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:164)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processOperator(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:131)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processAppearanceStringOperators(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:107)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.<init>(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:85)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDVariableText.getDefaultAppearanceString(PDVariableText.java:93)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.<init>(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:94)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:262)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:228)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:218)
```

I am running PDFBox 2.0.4 which is the newest version. My webserver most likely does not have access to write to `.pdfbox.cache` in the default location (which seems to be the JVM property `user.home`). Is there any way to disable the disk caching or change the location of the cache file?

I did notice that I can set a JVM wide system property called `pdfbox.fontcache`, but my webapp shares a jvm with other applications so this isn't an optimal solution. I also tried using that solution and setting the `pdfbox.fontcache` to `/tmp`, but it didn't actually create a file (although it now only throws the stacktrace once per boot).

I looked into the code in the [`FileSystemFontProvider`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/FileSystemFontProvider.java) and the problematic code seems to be in the [`saveDiskCache`](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/FileSystemFontProvider.java#L306) method. In that method, it first tries to write the file, but a FileNotFoundException is thrown instead of a SecurityException. FileNotFoundException inherits from IOException.

```
File file = getDiskCacheFile();
try
{
     writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
}
catch (SecurityException e)
{
     return;
}
```

Comment: IMO it doesn't matter if other applications have the same modified font cache location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set `pdfbox.fontcache` with a temporary folder like `/tmp` where your JVM can write new file inside then a cache file called `.pdfbox.cache` can be created when you generate PDF with PDFBox (I also use PDFBox 2.0.4).

Maybe your JVM cannot create a new file inside your `/tmp` directory? To check this try to create a new file with the user running your JVM with an interactive command prompt (shell).

With the command `ls -lA /tmp` you should see a `.pdfbox.cache` file in the temporary folder that you configure (example with a tomcat JVM and user):

> -rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  2050 Dec 29 16:13 .pdfbox.cache

It's not an optimal solution because you can't set multiple `pdfbox.fontcache` system property on a single JVM.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but in which jvm-config file exactly can I set the pdfbox.fontcache-property so that it will act "system-widely"?

Comment: @tombo_189 it's a system property, you can set it with the `java -D` option like this: `java -Dpdfbox.fontcache=/tmp ...`


If you can also set it programmatically with a `System.setProperty("pdfbox.fontcache", "/tmp");` call in an initialization code.

Comment: `System.setProperty("pdfbox.fontcache", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));`